# I face an issue regarding the file upload in Digital Ocean space using java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, image-uploading, digital-ocean

Is there any documentation API for Java conectivity with "Digital Ocean". Or else any alternative approach is present. If not possible in java can i use the php as an interface to toggle with this aspect.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: The *one* way I see how you could turn your request into a "on topic" question would be to create a [mcve] with the code you have to ask for help fixing your broken code. But this community is **not** about finding documentation for you, nor about broadly explaining an API on the level of detail that you would find in an external tutorial / API spec.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"https://icdu91.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/digitalocean-spaces-java-example/"

refer the above link. It supports the java to digital ocean api connectivity.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!